# vim running in tmux permanently freezes when I accidentally type C-x s

Tags: vim, tmux, emacs

I use emacs a lot, and type <kbd>C-x s</kbd> to save there. When I am in vim running inside tmux on a remote machine, if I accidentally type <kbd>C-x s</kbd>, the vim instance completely freezes up, and the only way out is to send `tmux` the `kill-pane` command.

How can I configure vim/tmux to block this from happening?

Comment: Are you in Insert mode at the time?

Comment: I've checked, it freezes vim in insert mode as well as command mode

Comment: are you typing control+s ? that can freeze terminals until control+q is pressed

Answer (score 3):

@thrig answered my question, I can type <kbd>C-q</kbd> to get out of the frozen state I was in. Thank you!

Comment: This is an interesting difference between VIM and NeoVIM.  NeoVIM's raw mode turns off flow control special character processing in the line discipline.  VIM's leaves it on.

Comment: I've been wondering how neovim is different than vim, thanks for sharing!